# rails with apache2 and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger

I install rails follow this [tutorial](http://bootpolish.net/home_howto_installrubyonrails3ondebianlenny), install a demo app and I added this lines in the file sites-available/mysite.com

```
...
DocumentRoot /path/mysite.com/public
RailsEnv development
RackEnv development
...
```

when I try connect to the url I get

```
Not Found

The requested URL /rails/info/properties was not found on this server.
```

Comment: tail -f logs/error.log  
Premature end of script headers:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're clicking the *"About your application’s environment"* link on the Rails default index.html page.  This link only works in `development` environment, not in `production`.

The idea is to remove that `public/index.html` file altogether before shipping to production.

Comment: ok. but, when I remove public/index.html . I get 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Then you need to define a root route in `config/routes.rb` - see [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: in `config/routes.rb` I have `root :to => 'pages#home'`

Comment: Then check your log file for why the server is throwing that error.  Could be that passenger isn't set up correctly, could be a number of things.